# How array task if all of them is passed in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
tasks: [
{failed: true, remarks: "",task: {'name': 'task1'}},
{failed: true, remarks: "",task: {'name': 'task2'}},
]
```

How to check all task if it's all failed?

like for example if all task is `failed: true` then it should be `FAILED`

if all of them `failed: false` then it should be `PASSED`

but when the data is like this:

```
   tasks: [
    {failed: failed, remarks: "",task: {'name': 'task1'}},
    {failed: true, remarks: "",task: {'name': 'task2'}},,
    {failed: true, remarks: "",task: {'name': 'task3'}}
    ]
```

then it automatically `FAILED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important condition in your ask is,

> if all of them failed: false then it should be PASSED

You'll need to handle that case, and every other case will be `FAILED`

You can use the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) iterator,

```
const status = tasks.every(task => task.failed === false) ? 'PASSED' : 'FAILED';
```

```js
let tasks = [{
    failed: true,
    remarks: "",
    task: {
      'name': 'task1'
    }
  },
  {
    failed: true,
    remarks: "",
    task: {
      'name': 'task2'
    }
  },
];

console.log(tasks.every(task => task.failed)); // output: true

let tasksWithFailed = [{
    failed: false,
    remarks: "",
    task: {
      'name': 'task1'
    }
  },
  {
    failed: true,
    remarks: "",
    task: {
      'name': 'task2'
    }
  },
];

console.log(tasksWithFailed.every(task => task.failed)); // output: false
```

Comment: so for example if there's only one failed in the tas it will automatically failed right?

Comment: Basically, if all tasks don't have `failed == false`, status will be FAILED